# ajax not working in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a post request using the ajax jquery function and return some data into a window asynchronously. Here's what I have so far. It doesn't seem to be working.

in the view:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/dashboard/presskits/media/get_video_link/',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { encoded_link : encoded_link },
          cache: false,
          success: function(output_string){
            // $('#edit_video_info').append(output_string);
            alert(output_string.url_data);
          } // End of success function of ajax form
          }); // End of ajax call
});
```

in the controller:

```
 public function get_video_link()
{
    $temp_url = $this->input->post('encoded_link');
    $output_string = json_encode(array('url_data' => $temp_url));
            return $output_string;
    }
```

Comment: You are using json so you need to return the json encode of the string `echo json_encode($output_string);`

Answer (score 1):

Print or echo not return the JSON and you should include the success too.

```
print json_encode(array('Status' =>'Success', 'url_data' => $temp_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your return with `echo` or `print`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have the URL helper enabled? I don't think your URL field is correct. Enable your URL helper within config and echo your base URL like so

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/presskits/media/get_video_link/"
```

Also, I would recommend using the chrome or firefox developer tool to check the HTTP response header from your request. On Chrome, just do Right-Click->Network, and then fire off your ajax request.

Second, you should be echoing the response in your controller, not returning it. At a low level, when a function returns a value, it's storing that value in registers (memory) and it's all happening in the stack. In other words, it's not an I/O operation. Echo will output the json text directly to the browser (which is what the ajax call is expecting).